# 16.04 Display resolution changed itself without an upgrade/update and can't get it back

Tags: 16.04, nvidia, display-resolution

I realize this has been asked a thousand times but I cannot find a solution for my problem. I have only one monitor, I'm not using a grub menu and I'm on Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS xenial. So far the resolution was fine (1920x1080), but last Friday I turned off the computer and today the resolution changed to 1024x768. Display doesn't go higher than 1360x768. I'm using the graphics card from my NVIDIA driver (chaging to X.org Nouveau doens't work either).

**:~$ xrandr** :

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1360 x 768, maximum 16384 x 16384
VGA-0 connected primary 1360x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768      60.00 +
   1360x768      59.96*   59.80  
   1152x864      60.00  
   800x600       72.19    60.32    56.25  
   680x384       59.96    59.80  
   640x480       59.94  
   512x384       60.00  
   400x300       72.19  
   320x240       60.05  
DVI-D-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

**~:$ lshw -C video**:

```
  *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: NVIDIA Corporation
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
       resources: irq:127 memory:ee000000-eeffffff memory:e0000000-e7ffffff memory:e8000000-e9ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memory:c0000-dffff
```

I tried [this fix:](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg-server/+bug/1517046) but for some reason it doesn't work:

~:$ sudo xrandr  --newmode "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync

~:$ sudo xrandr --addmode VGA-0 1920x1080

```
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  18 (RRAddOutputMode)
  Serial number of failed request:  33
  Current serial number in output stream:  34
```

I also tried the same fix by editing with nano the **~/.xprofile**, and although I can do that with no errors when I reboot it doesn't do anything.

And I tried upgrading NVIDIA drivers but it broke my login screen (couldn't log in), so I had to purge all NVIDIA drivers and then reinstall the one I'm currently using (the one I was already using before).

Any ideas on how could I solve this problem?

Comment: comment (as in opinion) only: i have no special knowledge; but it seems to me you're blaming the OS claiming no change was made.  if that's true, it could be the screen is failing or has been changed (even cables); and its available resolutions reported via cable to the pc are now limited because of a change to config settings in your screen.  was the screen frequency changed over the weekend? (higher setting at lower res; left on and a cleaner dusting changed config without realizing??)

Comment: @guiverc I checked the history of apt-get and last time it was updated was on 09-14 (last Thursday). Since then I used it on Friday, and it didn't have this problem.  About the other changes you mention I can't be sure. But if that were the case, you have any idea how could I possibly solve this?

Comment: monitors are all different.  i've encountered a screen (hence my comment) that forced a (non-ubuntu) desktop to lower-res on next boot. I didn't understand the icons (lots of symbols) on the monitor, so i played with things until it returned to normal,  in my case it was menu/settings on display-monitor, but I've also been told changing screen cable can do the same thing (esp. if poor quality cable).

Comment: @guiverc I checked the cable and one of the connections was losen up!! Tightening the connection fixed it!! I feel stupid, but honestly I never heard a bad connection could cause a low resolution. If you answer the question I'll mark it as solved :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me you're blaming the OS claiming no change was made.

If that's true, it could be the screen is failing or has been changed (even cables); and its available resolutions reported via cable to the pc are now limited because of a change to config settings in your screen [or cable issue].

Was the screen changed over the weekend? A cleaner dusting changing config/cable without your knowledge?  Check screen & cable.